# Numpy: How to get the max bin position?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to find the max bin place of a 2d histogram

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100) * 10
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=20)

elements = (len(xedges) - 1) * (len(yedges) - 1)
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1]+0.25, yedges[:-1]+0.25)

xpos = xpos.flatten()
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos = np.zeros(elements)
dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = hist.flatten()

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, zsort='average')
plt.show()
```

[image]

That is, I want to know the (x,y) of the `hist.max()`.

I think I can get away with `hist.argmax()`. But I don't how to deal with the rest (converting 1d position into 2d). Or if there are better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

np.unravel_index is the most idiomatic way of solving this

Comment: So this would be `row, col = np.unravel_index(hist.argmax(),hist.shape)`? it would return the row, col, and then I can get the value a `xedges[row],yedges[col]`

Answer (score 1):

Divide the position in the flattened array by the number of columns and you'll get the row. The remainder is the column.

```
row, col = divmod(np.argmax(hist), hist.shape[0])
```